# LLVM build error due to no matching function

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-clang

I cloned the LLVM git repositories and followed https://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html. After configuration with

```
cmake $SOURCEDIR -G "Unix Makefiles" \
 -DCLANG_DEFAULT_CXX_STDLIB=libc++ \
 -DC_INCLUDE_DIRS=:/usr/include \
 -DLLVM_ENABLE_WERROR=OFF \
 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=DEBUG \
 -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=$CC \
 -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=$CXX \
 -DCMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS="${LDFLAGS}" \
 -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE="${CXXFLAGS}" \
 -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$INSTALLDIR \
 -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON
```

I tried to build LLVM and Clang with

```
make -j 24
```

but it failes (I added new lines for improved readability):

```
/home/myUserName/LLVM/sources/tools/clang/utils/TableGen/ClangAttrEmitter.cpp: 
In constructor ‘{anonymous}::EnumArgument::EnumArgument(const llvm::Record&, llvm::StringRef)’:

/home/myUserName/LLVM/sources/tools/clang/utils/TableGen/ClangAttrEmitter.cpp:740:42: 
error: no matching function for call to 
‘std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::vector(std::vector<llvm::StringRef>)’
     uniques(uniqueEnumsInOrder(enums))
                                      ^
```

Unfortunately I don't understand why there is a problem, since this function should be declared in

```
tools/clang/utils/TableGen/ClangAttrEmitter.cpp:722.
```

This is an excerpt of the corresponding code:

```
// Unique the enums, but maintain the original declaration ordering.
std::vector<std::string>
uniqueEnumsInOrder(const std::vector<std::string> &enums) {
 std::vector<std::string> uniques;
 SmallDenseSet<StringRef, 8> unique_set;
 for (const auto &i : enums) {
   if (unique_set.insert(i).second)
     uniques.push_back(i);
 }    
 return uniques;
}

class EnumArgument : public Argument {
 std::string type;
 std::vector<std::string> values, enums, uniques;
public:
 EnumArgument(const Record &Arg, StringRef Attr)
   : Argument(Arg, Attr), type(Arg.getValueAsString("Type")),
     values(Arg.getValueAsListOfStrings("Values")),
     enums(Arg.getValueAsListOfStrings("Enums")),
     uniques(uniqueEnumsInOrder(enums))
 {    
   // FIXME: Emit a proper error
   assert(!uniques.empty());
 }
```

I use gcc 7.2.0 and Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS.

**Update:**

In the meantime I had the chance to build LLVM+Clang with gcc 5.4.0 and the build finished successfully. Does this mean that there is a compiler bug oder is it an issue respectively the gcc standard?

Comment: Can you post relevant source code too?

Comment: @Asesh Have added the relevant code section