# LLVM Build Error (missing function again)

Tags: c++, cmake, clang, llvm, build-error

Note: I have already seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46893355/llvm-build-error-due-to-no-matching-function), and I know that this is a different function.

I am building clang alongside LLVM, and I am getting an error of (broken up):

```
no matching function for call to ‘sort(
    std::vector<
        clang::DocumentationData>&, 
        clang::EmitClangAttrDocs(
            llvm::RecordKeeper&,
            llvm::raw_ostream&
        )::<
            lambda(
                const clang::DocumentationData&,
                const clang::DocumentationData&
            )
        >
    )
’
```

The function call is:

```
llvm::sort(I.second,
    [](const DocumentationData &D1, const DocumentationData &D2) {
        return D1.Heading < D2.Heading;
    });
```

Any help?

Comment: And what function are you expecting that to match?

Comment: I don't know. This is a part of clang, not my code. I will try changing versions and seeing if that does anything.

Comment: Is there any solution to this by now? I am having the same issue.